# executables / process start and stop

Tags: android

I got this assignment on android and I don't know really much about it and cant find anything useful on goggle, so here it is:

I need to create a application on android (any OS) that start and stop executable,
my first question is what is executable? is it a process? it related to Zygote?

if its a process can you send me a nice reference or examples of process starting and stopping.

again I couldn't find anything useful.

thanks,
sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: If Android was not specified as the target of the assignment, then it's probably a poor choice on your part, as Android does not really use processes in the traditional way - while you can launch and kill processes **belonging to a userid you have access to** in the normal Linux way, those processes have difficulty interacting with the user, and trying to utilize them puts you a bit at odds with the Android platform and far outside normal android development guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your assignment is about Android's internals (which I doubt), your *process* is a normal app and your *executable* an .apk file. You shouldn't need to care about Zygote as well! For basic tutorials about Android I suggest [Vogella's tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/android.html)!

Comment: @joseRo: A reference of what? I included a link in my answer... And I'm surely not going to walk you through your first app!